# adding data string to array

Tags: iphone, ipad

i got string which is 
String *newID=@"12390,12391,12392,12394,12394,12395,12396"

this is the request send to me.

I need to add each id from string into NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *newID=@"12390,12391,12392,12394,12394,12395,12396";
NSMutableArray *arrayIds = [[newID componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: can we do this for 
 NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary

Answer (score 1):

array = [newID componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSString *newID=@"12390,12391,12392,12394,12394,12395,12396";
NSArray *arrays = [newID componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrays];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *newID=@"12390,12391,12392,12394,12394,12395,12396";  
NSArray *arrayIds = [newID componentsSeparatedByString:@","];  
NSString *str1=[arrayIds objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *str2=[arrayIds objectAtIndex:1];  
.  
.  
.
```

Answer (score 0):

NSString *newID=@"12390,12391,12392,12394,12394,12395,12396";

array=[newID componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

(if you use another method)[array retain];